# A Counter Example about Closed Graph Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, self-learning, banach-spaces

This is an example I read around closed graph theorem. Let $Y=C[0, 1]$ and $X$ be its subset $C^\infty[0, 1]$. Equip both with uniform norm. Define $D: X \to Y$ by $f \mapsto f'$. Suppose $(f_n, f_n') \to (g, h)$ in $X \times Y$. Thus, $f_n \to g, f_n' \to h$ both uniformly on $[0, 1]$. It is well known that $g' = h$. Thus, the graph of $D$ is closed. But since $D(t^n) = nt^{n-1}$, $D$ is not continuous. I have three questions about this example.

1. Why $f_n \to g, f_n' \to h$ both ***uniformly*** on $[0, 1]$?
2. Why $g' = h$ ***even though it is well known***?
3. Why $D$ is not continuous ***because*** $D(t^n) = nt^{n-1}$?

Could anyone explain these questions to me, please? Thank you!

Comment: 4. Why is that **not** a counterexample to the closed graph theorem?

Comment: @DanielFischer In this case, the graph is closed but the function $D$ is not continuous provided everything is right in the book.

Comment: Yes. And why does that not contradict the closed graph theorem?

Comment: @DanielFischer Because $X$ is not complete?

Comment: **1.** what is the topology of $X \times Y$?

Comment: @GEdgar Induced from the uniform norm?

Comment: Yes, because $X$ is not complete.

Comment: @DanielFischer What is an example to show that $X$ is not complete?

Comment: $$f_n(x) = \sqrt{(x-\tfrac{1}{2})^2 + \tfrac{1}{n}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The topology on $X\times Y$ is given by the norm $\|(x,y)\|=\max\{\|x\|,\|y\|\}$. So if $(f_n,f_n')\to(f,g)$, this means that $\|f_n-f\|\to0$, $\|f_n'-g_n\|\to0$, i.e. $f_n\to f$, $f_n'\to g$ uniformly.
2. Fix $x\in X$. Then 
   \begin{align}
   \left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h-g(x)\right|
   &\leq\left|\frac{f(x+h)-f_n(x+h)}h\right|+\left|\frac{f_n(x+h)-f_n(x)}h-g(x)\right|
   +\left|\frac{f_n(x)-f(x)}h\right|\\ \ \\
   &\leq\frac{2\|f_n-f\|}h+\left|\frac{f_n(x+h)-f_n(x)}h-g(x)\right|\\ \ \\
   &=\frac{2\|f_n-f\|}h+\left|f_n'(\xi_{h,n})-g(x)\right|  \ \ \ \ \ \ \textit{(Mean Value Theorem)}\\ \ \\
   &\leq\frac{2\|f_n-f\|}h+\left|f_n'(\xi_{h,n})-f_n'(x)\right|+\left|f_n'(x)-g(x)\right|\\ \ \\
   &\leq\frac{2\|f_n-f\|}h+\left|f_n'(\xi_{h,n})-f_n'(x)\right|+\left\|f_n'-g\right\|\\ \ \\
   \end{align}
   Now fix $\varepsilon>0$. As $f_n'$ is uniformly continuous and $\xi_{h,n}$ lies between $x$ and $x+h$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that if we take $|h|<\delta$  we get $|f_n'(\xi_{h,n})-f_n'(x)|<\varepsilon/3$. So for $|h|<\delta$, we have 
   \begin{align}
   \left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h-g(x)\right|
   &\leq\frac{2\|f_n-f\|}h+\frac\varepsilon3+\left\|f_n'-g\right\|,
   \end{align}
   for every $n$. Now we can take $n$ big enough so that $\|f_n-f\|<h/6\varepsilon$ and $\|f_n'-g\|<\varepsilon/3$, so 
   \begin{align}
   \left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h-g(x)\right|
   &\leq\frac\varepsilon3+\frac\varepsilon3+\frac\varepsilon3=\varepsilon.
   \end{align}
3. If $f(t)=t^n$, then $\|f\|=\sup\{|t^n|:\ t\in[0,1]\}=1$. And
   $$
   \|Df\|=\sup\{|nt^{n-1}|:\ t\in [0,1]\}=n. 
   $$
   So $D$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 4):

**3.**

$D(t^n) = nt^{n-1}$. But $\|t^n\| = 1$ and $\|D(t^n)\| \to \infty$.
So $D$ is not a bounded operator.  You know, right, that for linear operator on normed spaces, continuity holds iff the operator is bounded?

Comment: Oh, yes. Thanks. What about other items, please?