# Showing that $f^{'} = g$ and that the graph of $D$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

**problem:** Consider the space $Y = C([0,1], \mathbb{R})$ of continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Let $$ X := \left\{ f \in Y \mid f^{'} \ \text{exists and is continuous on} \ [0,1] \right\} $$ Equip both $Y$ and $X$ with the norm $|| . ||_{\infty}$. Consider the operator $D: X \rightarrow Y$ given by $Df = f^{'}$. Clearly $D$ is linear. Suppose that $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence in $X$ such that $(f_n, f_n^{'}) \rightarrow (f,g) $ in $X \oplus_1 Y$. Then $f_n^{'} \rightarrow g$ uniformly on $[0,1]$.

(i) Show that $f^{'} = g$ and hence deduce that the graph of $D$ is bounded.

(ii) Show that $D$ is not a bounded operator (hint: consider $f_n(t) = t^n$).

**attempt:** (i) I wish to show that $|| f^{'} - g ||_{\infty} = 0$. What I did was $$ || f^{'} - g ||_{\infty} \leq || f^{'} - f_n^{'}||_{\infty} + || f_n^{'} - g ||_{\infty}. $$ Since it is given that $f_n^{'} \rightarrow g$ uniformly, we have that $||f_n^{'} - g||_{\infty} \to 0$ (this is a standard result for the sup norm). But I was stuck at figuring out how to get $|| f^{'} - f_n^{'}||_{\infty} $ small. I can say that $$|| f^{'} - f_n^{'}||_{\infty} \leq || D || \ || f - f_n ||_{\infty}. $$ Then since it is given that $(f_n, f_n^{'}) \rightarrow (f,g)$, I think that $||f - f_n||_{\infty} \to 0$. But I'm worried that since $D$ is not bounded, I cannot get $|| D|| $ small to get this argument to work...

(ii) For this part, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and all $t \in [0,1]$ with $t \neq 0$ I think we have $$ \frac{ | n t^{n-1}|}{ | t^n|} \geq n. $$ This would show that $$ \frac{ || D f_n||}{ || f_n||} \geq n$$ and so $D$ is unbounded. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992580/a-counter-example-about-closed-graph-theorem

Answer (score 1):

You're right about (ii). About (i), think about what does it mean that $(f_n,f_n')\to (f,g)$ in $X\oplus Y$. You can show that it implies that $f_n\to f$ in $X$ which means, by definition of $||\cdot||_\infty$, that $||f-f_n||_\infty\to 0$.

Comment: Yes but we have the term $|| D || || f - f_n||_{\infty}$. Does the term $|| D ||$ not matter? That was my question.